# moving table to another tablespace in primary server oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

What will be the effect on dataguard configuration when moving one table to another tablespace using the `impdp` `remap_tablespace` parameter?

In our production environment we have setup dataguard and I am curious that if move a table in primary what will be effect on dataguard or what steps should I do before the moving table.

Answer (score 4):

If you have configured Data Guard properly, this will not cause any problem. And by 'properly', I mean `FORCE LOGGING` is enabled. Data Pump can use direct path load (in which case there is minimal redo  generated), but there are several conditions that will prevent it:

[Situations in Which Direct Path Load Is Not Used](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL805)

Anyway, to check `FORCE LOGGING`:

```
select force_logging from v$database;
```

If the result is `NO`, you can enable it with:

```
alter database force logging;
```

Note that, this should be done on the primary and all standby databases as well (just in case a role transition happens and a standby becomes primary).

Comment: Thanks Balaz, yes force logging is enable on primary as well as on Standby.  Following command will use  impdp user/pwd  directory=EXPORT_DIR dumpfile=TABLE_EXPORT.dmp tables=GEOPOLI  table_exists_action=replace remap_tablespace=Tablespace1:Tablespace2  logfile=GEOPOLITable_Import_dp.log